# Por que das regras de colocação pronominal?

Tags: origem-histórica, mudanças-históricas

Quando aprendi as regras de colocação pronominal, achei-as bem estranhas, exceto a que “proíbe” próclise em início de oração e a que “força” ênclise em imperativo, soando-me melhor dizer «puseram-na numa situação difícil» do que «a puseram numa situação difícil». Eu achava que os portugueses seguissem essas regras a ferro e fogo, mas os vejo preferindo quase sempre a ênclise à próclise — os que vi eram jovens. Ademais, na língua (bem) antiga, dava-se grande preferência à próclise, também porque lhes soavam mal palavras proparoxítonas.

Então, por que das regras de colocação pronominal? ou seja, donde vieram?

Comment: Eu creio que vêm, tal como a norma gramatical brasileira em geral, da maneira como escreviam os escritores do romantismo, portugueses na sua maioria. Eu só dei atenção a essas "regras" quando comecei a frequentar aqui o site (não se aprende colocação pronominal na escola em Portugal), e então descobri que o que os sites brasileiros prescrevem é mais ou menos como eu falo! Mas realmente já ouvi pessoal, sobretudo mais novo, a usar a ênclise em situações em que eu uso a próclise; soa-me muita estranho.

Comment: Essa pergunta abrange muito história e não funciona bem aqui, na minha humilde opinião. Jacinto terá de escrever um livro. :)

Comment: Também acho que esta pergunta é demasiado complexa para o formato deste site.  Existe muita literatura sobre o assunto, mas as explicações e as formalizações gramaticais além de complexas também diferem muito. E sim, em Portugal existe uma tendência cada vez maior para usar a ênclise, especialmente entre as gerações mais jovens, mas não só. Isto é um fenómeno que já era apontado há três, quatro décadas, (pelo menos) mas creio estar a acelerar.

Comment: @Schilive, não entendi bem a tua pergunta. Há diferenças no uso pronominal entre PTPT, PTBR, PTAN. Em PTPT eu escolheria nitidamente "puseram-na numa situação difícil". A segunda variante só em orações subordinadas "ele disse que a puseram numa situação difícil".  Não entendi qual a relação com as palavras esdrúxulas (ou  proparoxítonas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colocação pronominal no galego-português era mais parecida com as outras línguas românicas e o português brasileiro atual. Depois, durante a renascença, o padrão continuou basicamente o mesmo, por isso é muito comum encontrarmos próclise n'Os Lusíadas, coisas como "me ajude", que eram comuns na época.

O que houve a seguir foi que o português brasileiro manteve a colocação pronominal com maior tendência proclítica, enquanto o português europeu foi mudando e tornando-se cada vez mais enclítico. A norma que se usa no português padrão e que é usada no mundo lusófono reflete principalmente o falar europeu neste quesito.

Assim, a regra mais geral é: no Brasil preserva-se mais a próclise, em Portugal usa-se mais a ênclise!